# Initialize a variable multiple times

Tags: constructor, heap-memory

I have a static function for serializing Xml document, of a particular input type.
Following are the approaches:

```
 Approach 1.
 public static XmlDocument SerializeToXmlDocument<T>(this T o)
 {
      XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

      using (XmlWriter writer = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
      {
           XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
           xmls.Serialize(writer, o);
      }

      return xmlDoc;
 }

 Approach 2.
 static XmlSerializer xmls;
 public static XmlDocument SerializeToXmlDocument<T>(this T o)
 {
      XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

      using (XmlWriter writer = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
      {
           if (xmls == null || xmls.GetType() != typeof(T))
           {
                xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
           }
           xmls.Serialize(writer, o);
      }

      return xmlDoc;
 }
```

This method is called from various pages, so type could be different.

Which one should I use, considering minimum usage of memory. Also as my architect says that XmlSerializer is not collected by GC, it stays there. Have to work with this assumption only.

Q.1) Which approach is better, and why ? 
Q.2) And also, what happens if I initialize a single variable many times. Constructor will assign memory to object every time. But object has a reference, so will it get same memory space every time or a different one.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: No, this is real time situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach 2 is not thread-safe, so it will probably get you into trouble later on.

I would use approach 1, and only if there seems to be a performance problem consider some kind of approach 2 (but then thread-safe).

Comment: It could be a memory leak, because XmlSerializer remains there in memory and is not gone (collected by GC). So what happens if I initialize a single variable many times. Constructor will assign memory to object every time or it get same memory space every time as reference is same ?

Comment: According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on msdn (the paragraph on 'dynamically generates assemblies'), if you use this constructor (with the type argument) this should not be an issue.

Comment: Oh amazing that helps a lot! It also explains as why XmlSerializer is not collected by GC.